# What's a ".dll.a" file?

Tags: dll, winapi

I'm trying to use a open source library from a Windows application, and the only pre-built version I can find comes as a file called "lib.dll.a"

What format is this, and can I convert it to a normal dll file?

Answer (score 23):

Naming the output file `libjvm.dll.a` will allow `gcc` to recognize it as a
library named `jvm`. The `.dll.a` suffix indicates (by convention) that it is
an import library, rather than a static library (which would simply be named
`libjvm.a`, again by convention).

Comment: Sadly, I'm not using gcc : do you know what *format* this file is in ? OMF/COFF/something else, and can it be used with toolchains other than gcc?

Comment: Seems to be a set of object files archived with `ar`. `file` returns `COFF object file` for the `.o`s inside.

Comment: @Roddy I have the same issue - have you managed to link with those files? I use Visual Studio and was expecting .dll/.lib files and only have .dll.a/.a files and I'm stuck...

Answer (score -1):

Linux / MacOS / Linuxen have .a for static libraries and .so for dynamic libraries.

Windows has .lib for static libraries and (import) .lib + (matching) .dll for dynamic libraries.  The import.lib statically links the hooks needed to talk to the .dll library loaded later.

To help avoid the confusion with this, the Msys / MINGW people apparently decided to use .dll.a for the import .lib files.  You should be able to rename lib.dll.a to lib-import.lib. You might also be able to just link against them as if they were .lib.  The published FFMPEG shared package for Windows (via winget below) includes .a & .dll.a in the lib directory and executables & .dlls in the bin directory.  That makes sense because in Windows, .dlls are a type of executable in some ways.

https://www.gyan.dev/ffmpeg/builds/