# convert .dll.a to dll

Tags: dll

I download a autotrace library to use in my java project but it contains only (libautotrace.a, libautotrace.la, libautotrace.dll.a and header)

my question: is it possible to convert libautotrace.dll.a to dll library?

Comment: possible duplicate of [What's a ".dll.a" file?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/185326/whats-a-dll-a-file)

Answer (score 2):

You can not.

The dot-a files you have were compiled for a Unix system, and can not be directly converted to a Windows format.

You will need to find a windows-native build or the source code to build it yourself.