# What is a DLL.a file and how do I load one into my VC++ project

Tags: c++, visual-studio, dll

I have recently stumbled upon an open source project that I would like to take part in, but I've noticed that they have `DLL.a` files. I've never seen this file type before and as a programmer for a decent 5 years I've learned not to assume something that I don't understand.

Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What's a ".dll.a" file?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/185326/whats-a-dll-a-file)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These are archive files, which are static libraries intended for use on a Linux system. They won't work with Visual Studio, you'll need to find the Windows libraries (if they exist).

Comment: Thanks for letting me understand what these are.